# Visual Studio 2010 - Can't build web site which references 64 bit assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How can a web application reference a 64 bit assembly?

I have a solution with a web application and a class library.  The class library is set to build on 64bit. The web application by default is **Any CPU**, but if I build and run I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ClassLibrary64, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

I can't run the project on 32 bits or Any CPU - I'm interacting with SharePoint 2010, and the site *must* run in 64 bits or the SharePoint API doesn't work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm dealing with exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

IIS is probably running as 32-bit. Why don't you build the class library as AnyCPU?

Comment: The SharePoint object model (api's) are 64 bit and the projects that use it must be compiled as 64 (not anycpu).

Answer (score 0):

That will be because your web app is being JIT compiled to 32 bit, so you cannot load a 64 bit assembly into the worker process.

There are very few reasons why you need to compile a web app assembly to a particular bitness. Do you need the class library to be x64, or can you leave it as AnyCPU?

Also, is IIS running on a 64 bit machine with a 64 bit OS? If either is 32 bit only then you won't be able to load the 64 bit assembly anyway.

Comment: I am running code against SharePoint 2010 object model and exposing through a wcf service.  SharePoint 2010 is 64bit and as such code must be compiled 64 bit.  The issue here is that I need to interact with the 64 bit projects via a web service.  I can't leave as AnyCpu unfortunately.